# Android animation with KTX

Tags: android, android-animation, kotlin-android-extensions, android-ktx

I have some animations in my Android app and I'd like to change my code in order to take advantage of Android KTX. Sadly, I don't really understand [the documentation about it](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/animation/package-summary). Could someone tell me how I can improve this code with the help of Android KTX?

```
view
    .animate()
    .translationY(view.height.toFloat())
    .setDuration(3000)
    .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator())
    .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            // Do whatever I want
        }
    })
```

Of course, I have already added the dependency in my Gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Do you only need the `onAnimationEnd` method on the animator listener? The KTX extensions for the `Animator` aim to simplify the creation of your listeners.

Comment: @Edric Indeed I only need the ```onAnimationEnd```. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use AnimatorListenerAdapter class instead of AnimatorListener. You do not need ktx for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android KTX has `doOnEnd { /** Do whatever you want **/ }` and other extension functions for `android.animation.Animator`. When you call `view.animate()`, it returns `ViewPropertyAnimator` which is ***not*** inherited from `android.animation.Animator` class. Therefore you cannot `view.animate().doOnEnd { /** Do whatever you want **/ }` provided by Android KTX.

However, you can use [withEndAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#withEndAction(java.lang.Runnable)) to do anything when animation ends. `withEndAction` is part of default `ViewPropertyAnimator`, so, you do not need to have Android KTX to use that:

```
view
    .animate()
    .translationY(image.height.toFloat())
    .setDuration(3000)
    .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator())
    .withEndAction {
        // Do whatever you want
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

*Android KTX* provides some animation event listener functions for [`Animator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) instances. As `view.animate()` returns an instance of `ViewPropertyAnimator`, you should use a subclass of `Animator` (like `ObjectAnimator`) to be able to use *KTX* capabilities. for example:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", view.height.toFloat()).apply {
    duration = 3000
    interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
    // Using KTX extension function:
    doOnEnd { /** Do whatever you want **/ }
    start()
}
```